# Different rootviewcontrollers for targets

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have different targets for my project and i would like the following:

In my storyboard the rootviewcontroller is a TabbarController. Every tab is a NavigationController and a tableviewcontroller is the rootcontroller for every navigationcontroller. For one NavController there are two Tableviewcontrollers behind it.

Now for a second target for my project i need to start the application at the second tableviewcontroller, not the first.

How can i achieve this? I know how to select the target. I tried a lot of this in the AppDelegate. I know how to set the rootviewcontroller, but then the tableview has no tabbar and navigationbar that it inherits normally. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you done something similar to this?

```
var myTabBarController = UITabBarController()
myTabBarController.viewControllers = [navigationViewController1,navigationViewController1]

self.window!.rootViewController = myTabBarController;  
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a different macro define for each target and then have one source file which loads the different controller depending upon the macro.
Or separate the code doing the loading of the view controllers into two separate source files and build one source file with one target and another source file with the other target.